# My foreach statement won't work in the switch statement

Tags: php, function, foreach, switch-statement

This function has been puzzling me for some time now, I just cannot get the foreach statement to work, both of the cases work, because it'll show the words `Today` and `Yesterday` but the `year`, `month`, and `day` won't show up.

```
function time_decider($timestamp){

$date = date('m/d/Y', $timestamp);
$dif_date = date('m/d/Y',time() - (24 * 60 * 60));

$a = array( 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60  =>  'year',
                30 * 24 * 60 * 60       =>  'month',
                24 * 60 * 60            =>  'day',
                );

switch ($date) {
    case date('m/d/Y'):
        return "Today";
        break;
    case $dif_date:
        return "Yesterday";
        break;
    default:

        foreach ($a as $secs => $str) {
            $d = $etime / $secs;
            if ($d >= 1) {
                $r = round($d);
                return $r . ' ' . $str . ($r > 1 ? 's ago' : '');
                break;
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to surround the calculations with parenthesis? (12*30*24*60*60)

Comment: what kind of output are you expecting? and since $d is always zero you will never recieve any value from the function as it is now

Comment: @Digitalis just did it and nothing, and I'm trying to get the days, weeks, months, and years ago from that foreach.

Comment: I'm so stupid, that `$etime` is suppose to be `$timestamp` that just fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the function as it is now `$d` will allways be zero since `$etime` is not defined